# Can you choose fewer creatures than the value of your spellcasting modifier to automatically succeed on the saving throw of Freedom of the Waves?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

The **Freedom of the Waves** spell from *Tal’dorei Campaign Setting: Reborn* says (emphasis mine):

> You can choose a number of creatures **equal to** your spellcasting modifier (minimum of 1) to automatically succeed on this saving throw.

Many other features and spells like this use the wording "up to" rather than the "equal to" seen in *Freedom of the Waves*. For example, *Feather Fall* (emphasis mine):

> Choose **up to** five falling creatures within range

If the caster's spellcasting modifier is +4, is the caster left with only the choices of choosing 4 creatures or not choosing any, because it says "equal to"? Or could the caster choose 1, 2, or 3 creatures instead?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, this question has been asked before about a different feature with the same problematic wording.